# $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ have PDF: $f(x) = 3x^2$ for $x \in (0,1)$. For which $a$ sequence $Z_n = n^{\frac{1}{3}}(S_n - a)$ is convergent in $L^2$?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence

> Random variables $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ are independent and have distribution with PDF: $f(x) = 3x^2 \ \mathbb{1}_{(0,1)}(x)$. Check if sequence $S_n = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is convergent a. s. For which values of $a$ sequence $Z_n = n^{\frac{1}{3}}(S_n - a)$ is convergent in $L^2$?

---

In the case of convergence a. s. we can use Kologomorov's strong law of large numbers for random variables with the same distribution:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} [S_n] = \lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} \left[ \frac{1}{n}(X_1 + X_2 + (...) + X_n) \right] =$$
From linearity of expectation:
$$ = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}( \mathbb{E}[X_1] + \mathbb{E}[X_2] + (...) + \mathbb{E}[X_n])$$
We know that:
$$\mathbb{E}[X_1] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x \cdot f(x) dx = \int^{1}_{0} x \cdot 3x^2 dx = 3 \int^{1}_{0} x^3 dx = \frac{3}{4}$$

We get that:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \mathbb{E} [S_n] = \frac{1}{n}( \frac{3}{4} + \frac{3}{4} + (...) + \frac{3}{4}) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \cdot \frac{3}{4} \cdot n = \frac{3}{4}$$

Therefore we have convergence a. s. and the limit equal to $\frac{3}{4}$.

---

As for the values $a$ for which sequence $Z_n$ is convergent in $L^2$ I am lost. Obviously, $\frac{3}{4}$ is one of them since in that case we have $ \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{0}{n^3} = 0$. But, since we have $n^3$ in the denominator, there is "some force" that could be be used to "bring down" the remains from difference in the numerator. I have no idea how to find those.

sequence $Z_n = n^{\frac{1}{3}}(S_n - a)$ is convergent in $L^2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume that $Z_n\to Y$ in $L^2$, then $\mathbb E\left[Z_n^2\right]$ is bounded.

Since $$\mathbb E\left[Z_n^2\right] = n^{\frac23} \mathbb E\left[\left(S_n - a\right)^2\right] \ge n^{\frac23} \left(\mathbb E\left[S_n\right] - a\right)^2 = n^{\frac23} \left(\frac34 - a\right)^2$$

then the only possible value is $a = \frac34$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you :)